# Managing Data in The Response - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I'm developing a node.js project and it's becoming large with many endpoints. Now modifying the data in the response for each endpoint has become really tedious job since I have to jump between files. For e.g. if I have a user model, I wouldn't return all its information in the response, only selected ones, and same for all other models. I did a research to find any way to manage this efficiently, but couldn't find any solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good option for you is switching your API to GraphQL.

With GraphQL you can avoid underfetching and overfetching.

You can see more information about GraphQL here: https://graphql.org/